# How to log errors in react micro frontend

Tags: reactjs, sentry, micro-frontend

We are planning to re-structure our FE code to microFEs. The current app uses Sentry for error logging using error boundary component.

Before we move forward with microFE I have one doubt which I'm hoping to get an answer here.

Will the error boundary component at parent app capture all the errors emerging from the federated apps or do we need to have this component in all the federated apps(with their Sentry integration)?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have too much experience on mifrofrontends but this is my thoughts:

- Try to use the native way: Use console.log, .error, .info, .debug based on what do you need. It will be there for at leat 20 years more.
- Override the console global object to the library you want to use (now sentry, tomorrow datadog maybe? or cloudwatch?) Most of monitoring tools like Sentry do it when you load the library automatically.
- Try to use detailed errors on your catchs, but what do you need to be detailed?

#### An idea about detailed logs

- Include always the name of the project. (or microfrontend and component).  To easily find the source of the error. An idea is use a symbol to easy grouping with regex like #SearchComponent#
- Include all related info for the context of the error (but avoid passwords, and try to encrypt personal data with public + private keys when you need it on the logs). This could be a bit complex if the catch does not have access to the declared variables inside the try.

Good luck!